# jQuery Chained Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've done some research but haven't been able to find and answer.

I have 1 text input and 1 selectbox.

- If the selected value of the selectbox is 2, I 'd like the textbox to be hidden
- If the selected value of selectbox is 1, the textbox should appear.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Pricing</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <select class="form-control" name="pricing">
          <option>Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Value 1</option>
          <option value="2">Value 2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Our Text Input</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" name="pricing" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried any javascript

Comment: I tried a few codes but they did not work, so I removed them.

Comment: It is always better to share what ever you have tried than not sharing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign an id to the form-group then use that to hide/show that element

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Fiyatlandırma</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <select class="form-control" name="fiyatlandirma">
          <option>Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Value 1</option>
          <option value="2">Value 2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="fiyat-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Our Text Input</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="fiyat" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
//dom ready handler - wait for the element to load
jQuery(function($){
    //change event handler to trigger when the select is changed
    $('select[name="fiyatlandirma"]').change(function(){
        //hide or display the group element based on the value of select
        $('#fiyat-group').toggle(this.value == '2')
    }).change();//to set the initial display state
})
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/
- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/
- http://api.jquery.com/change
- http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select.form-control").change(function(){
     if($(this).val()=="1")
       $("input[name=fiyat]").hide();
     else
       $("input[name=fiyat]").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give id to all three fields: select, input label and input box

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pricing").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            $("#textbox").hide();
            $("#textLabel").hide();
        } else {
            $("#textbox").show();
            $("#textLabel").show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Pricing</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <select class="form-control" name="pricing" id="pricing">
          <option>Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Value 1</option>
          <option value="2">Value 2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" id="textLabel">Our Text Input</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" name="pricing" id="textbox" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using java script

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Fiyatlandırma</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="select" name="fiyatlandirma"  onclick="hide()">
      <option>Please Select</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2" >Value 2</option>
   </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Our Text Input</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" id="fiyat" name="fiyat" class="form-control">
    </div>
 </div>

 <script>
     function hide(){
      var select = document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex;
      var input = document.getElementById("fiyat");
      if(select == 1)
      input.style.visibility= "hidden";
      else if(select == 2)
      input.style.visibility= "visible";
     }
</script>
```